# Embed and manage Google Forms in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-forms

I have the following use case.

Status quo:

We have a NodeJS app running that is not publicly accessible. We'd like to introduce some kind of form to acquire some data of the users/participants and that is used for another follow-up process upon completion of the form.

As we'd like to have a quick but also nice solution, I thought about embedding a Google Form as an iFrame in the app that we have already prepared some time beforehand. The Google form also gives us some additional features regarding the form creation that I don't know would be available in any Node native libraries or would be time-consuming to build, I assume. Moreover, we are partly working in the Google world so there might be some easy and fluid workflows possible.

Goal:

Now, my goal or rather problem with using the above-mentioned method is that I don't receive any notification, leave alone the responses, upon completion of the form.
I know the responses can be saved in a Sheet in Google Drive that could be requested by the app but I still don't know when someone has filled out the form in the app so that the follow-up process in the app can immediately be triggered.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I maybe thought about a Pub/Sub topic that was pushed to the app but then, again, the app is not publicly accessible.

Comment: It seems google pubsub doesn't need to make request to your server (like a webhook), its using other method ( http long polling/ websocket / grpc).